# workbook: dynamic worksheets not accessible in subroutine

Tags: excel, perl, subroutine, worksheet

So I'm creating a workbook in a subroutine called CreateWorkbook, dynamically adding worksheets using SQL query, and assigning worksheets to an %ws object. When exporting, the workbook has all tabs.

However, I'm having a problem accessing those worksheets in another subroutine. See my code below

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


my @lang_ids;
my @lang_types_ids;

sub run {
    my ($self, $app_id, $filepath, $args) = @_;
    my $workbook = CreateWorkbook($filepath, $app_id, $report_type, $lang_ids);
    return {};
}
```

This one creates workbook and worksheets using all available languages like: English, Spanish, German and etc.
Individual worksheets are references by the object **%ws** which is being passed. If I hardcode **$ws{test}**, that works fine.
Dynamic **$ws{\$final_name}** is adding worksheets with the correct name, for example, **$ws{spanish}** and when I export excel I can see all individual tabs.

```
sub CreateWorkbook {
    my ($filepath, $app_id, $report_type, $lang_ids) = @_;

    #print "Print filepath: $filepath    \n";
    my $sth;

    my $workbook_writer = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new($filepath);
    die "Problems creating new Excel file: $!" unless defined $workbook_writer;

    my %fmt;

    $fmt{fmt_normal} = $workbook_writer->add_format(num_format => '@');
    $fmt{fmt_normal}->set_size(11);

    my %ws;


    #this line works great and I'm able to access it in subroutine
    $ws{test} = $workbook_writer->add_worksheet('test');


    foreach my $lang_id (@lang_ids) {
        $sth = $app_id->_dbh->prepare(
            "SELECT name FROM languages where id = ?")
        || die("Problem preparing query");
        $sth->execute($lang_id) || die("Problem executing query");

        while ( my $name = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
            $name=~s/ /_/g;
            my $final_name = lc $name;

            #line below adds worksheet to workbook but cannot be accessed in subroutine
            $ws{\$final_name} = $workbook_writer->add_worksheet($name);

        }
    }

    $workbook_writer->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";

    
    return {
        fmt                 => \%fmt,
        ws                  => \%ws,
        workbook_writer     => $workbook_writer,
    };
```

And here's the problem, accessing **$ws{test}** works correctly but I cannot access **$ws{\$final_name}** even if I hardcode the value like **$ws{spanish}**

```
sub add_data {
    my ($app_id, $workbook, $report_type, $lang_ids, $lang_types_ids) = @_;

    my %fmt = %{ $workbook->{fmt} };
    my %ws = %{ $workbook->{ws} };
    my %workbook_writer = %{ $workbook->{workbook_writer} };

    my $sth;
    my $sth2;

    foreach my $lang_id (@lang_ids) {
        $sth = $app_id->_dbh->prepare(
            "SELECT name FROM languages where id = ?")
        || die("Problem preparing query");
        $sth->execute($lang_id) || die("Problem executing query");

        while ( my $name = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
            
            $name=~s/ /_/g;
            my $final_name = lc $name;

            #THIS WORKS FINE
            $ws{test}->write( 0, $languages, $name . " - " . $lang_id, $fmt{fmt_normal} );

            #ERROR: cannot call write method on undefined 
            $ws{\$final_name}->write( 0, $languages, $name . " - " . $lang_id, $fmt{fmt_normal} );
        }
    }

}
```

I spent way too much time on it. I checked if those worksheets are assigned to object variable in **CreateWorkbook** subroutine and they are but cannot access them outside of that subroutine.

I really appreciate any help. I assume I'm passing it incorrectly or not dereferencing it.

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to take a reference to `$final_name`. Try removing the backslash from it. ie. replace `$ws{\$final_name}` with `$ws{$final_name}` every place it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a misunderstanding of Perl references; nothing to do with workbooks or worksheets.

If `%ws` is a hash and `$final_name` is a string, then `$ws{\$final_name} = ...` creates a hash entry that looks like this : `$ws{'SCALAR(0x25f79c0)'} = ...`

In other words, the hash key is not the string, but the memory location where that key is stored. Remove the backslash, and you get a hash entry properly indexed by the actual content of `$final_name`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you both are right. 

That was the first thing I've tried and it didn't worked. So if I include all in one subroutine it works. So I believe the problem is with passing workbook and parameters.

Unfortunately I had to ditch those subroutines and create all in one subroutine. I will def research that more but many thanks for your help.